# Nativescript fetch default timeout

Tags: typescript, fetch, nativescript

i'm using nativescripts fetch api to retrieve informations from a backend.
Currently there are some strange behaviour and i wondered if the standard fetch of nativescript has a default timeout.

In axios for example you would have default 0 (no timeout) but how is it with fetch of nativescript and is it possible to set a timeout via the fetch command or do i need to do a workaround.

The only documentation i found was this
https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/fetch

Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: No default timeout is set in the polyfill used in NativeScript - here is the codebase https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/nativescript-core/fetch/fetch.js

Comment: Perhaps you could use something like this (for creating your own timeout) https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/175#issuecomment-216791333